# Create a fake Database for testing API with wagtail

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I need to create some tests against my APIs.
APIs use wagtail pages and serve me the contents of them.
I'm at the point of creating the database for the tests, but I'm not able to create wagtail pages, because I always get

```
ValidationError: {'path': [u'This field cannot be blank.'], 'depth': [u'This field cannot be null.']}
```

How can I do it? Do I have to create the entire site from the root down to the tree?

Comment: Provide a [mcve], please. It's not clear what exactly your problem is here. It looks like you are not providing data for all required fields in your http POST.

Answer (score 1):

`depth` - it's a nesting level. The ROOT page has level 1, the main page has level 2, Obviously, only 1 page can be on the first and second level

`path` - this is a specific value, which I have not yet understood.

The ROOT page (`depth` = 1) has this path: `0001`,

The main page on the second nesting level (`depth` = 2) has the path `00010001`.

The first page on the third nesting level (`depth` = 3) has the path `000100010001`

I can not guarantee that I give you advice that will work, since I did it for a long time,
But if you want to generate fake pages at the same level of nesting, you only need to change the path, adding + 1 to the last digit, and leaving the depth unchanged.

By example:

```
from yourapp.models import FakePage
k = 1
for i in range(5):
    k = k + 1
    page = FakePage(
    title = ('faketitle{}').format(k),
    path = ('{0:04}').format(k)
    depth = 3,
    )
    page.save()
```

But there is a better way:

```
from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page
from yourapp.models import FakePage

pages = Page.objects.all() # Get all pages

page = Page.objects.get(pk=3) # For example, take a page with pk = 3

fakepage = FakePage(title='fakepage title') # Create the desired page

page.add_child(instance=fakepage) # Add children page to the parrent page
```

In this case, you do not need to worry about the depth and the path.